# Selenium BeautifulSoup strange error

Tags: python, django, selenium, beautifulsoup

In my Django app I use selenium to fetch the page and BeautifulSoup to parse the html. I am working in Debian with Xvfb. This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

os.environ["DISPLAY"]=":99"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("www.google.it")
text = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)  

(... some code to parse the page with ...)
```

I have a very strange error: if I search in "soup" nothing is found. This does not happen on my local Windows XP machine. In "text" there is the html.

UPDATE: I think it's probably a codec/decode error but I don't know how to handle it in this case.

Comment: I assume that somewhere in there you are doing `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` yes? What does `soup.prettify()` show?

Comment: Also, when you say "if I search in soup nothing is found" ... can you be more specific? What is the code you're using to test that search?

Comment: @Amanda: Yes I'm doing from bs4 import BeautifulSoup. soup.prettify() show the html(). I have test this html e I found it's incorrect. This is the error. When I do: soup = BeautifulSoup(text) I get a "wrong" soup. Could be wrong my version of the browser in debian?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually fetching the page, so there is nothing to parse.  WebDriver expects a valid url (beginning with "http://" or "https://")

you should change the following line:

```
driver.get("www.google.it")
```

to:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.it")
```